# modelling claim loss using tweedie distribution in R

Tags: r, poisson, gamma-distribution, tweedie

i want to fit a tweedie compound Poisson Gamma to my loss data using ptweedie.series R command. I am getting problems how to start with my fitting in R. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Voting to close on the basis of extreme vagueness.

Answer (score 2):

Performing such a fit is illustrated here:

```
library(tweedie)
example("tweedie-package")
```